# Compilation of javascript file is taking 7 seconds due to which is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, web-performance

I'm dynamically creating an Iframe and injecting and external scripts in to it.

```
      function addScript(id, url, true) {
                            var script = window.document.createElement('script'),
                                deferredLoaded = $q.defer();

                            script.async = true;
                            script.id = id;
                            script.src = url;
                            script.type='text/javascript';

                            script.onload = script.onerror = function() { 
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
                            deferredLoaded.resolve(true);};

                            window.document.body.appendChild(script);

                            return deferredLoaded.promise;
                        }
```

above is the function which injects and downloads script dynamically.

issue i'm facing is , the script file which i created is getting compiled and evaluated on the main thread of chrome due to which my page is unresponsive for that duration.

but the on mozilla and safari i'm not facing this issue the page is smooth

https://blog.chromium.org/2014/02/compiling-in-background-for-smoother.html
it tells we can compile on background script streaming thread but i'm unable to achieve it
.
   Thanks.

Comment: Does it help to set `script.defer=true` Async should not make a difference for scripts added by script: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async I think parsing and executing script would always cause rendering to stop unless it's a web worker but loading script can block rendering if it's in html and not async. Not sure what version you used but in Chrome 62 `document.createElement("script").async` is true (as it should be by default for script created by script)

Comment: tried with script.defer=true, even that is causing page freeze.     yea using chrome 64 canvary. i have gone through a link of chromiumblog.                              [link]https://blog.chromium.org/2014/02/compiling-in-background-for-smoother.html